# IBM Cognos Cross Tab alignment

Tags: cognos

I have placed two crosstabs one below another. But They are not getting aligned. How to align the two cross tabs such that corresponding columns align perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty way is to use fixed widths on all cells.

This will work fine for PDF, but will not work for HTML if:

1. You're using a modern browser (IE9+, FF/Chrome from last 5 years)
2. The total width exceeds screen size
3. There is no total width set on the crosstab itself

It will then ignore the cell widths and try to force everything to the screen width, thus the crosstabs will not align again.

I wrote some JavaScript awhile back which will combine two tables into one so fixed width is not needed. [The full blog post is here](http://therealtoddnappi.blogspot.com/2013/05/cognos-form-basedaccounting-report_14.html). This will only affect HTML outputs, so for PDF I created a second page and just [conditionally rendered](http://therealtoddnappi.blogspot.com/2013/05/cognos-conditional-rendering-for.html) one depending on user selection.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed width is the only viable solution )
But you can use Report Classes to have a single “width” definition and apply it everywhere. It actually makes your reports look way neater.

Answer (score 0):

Use Blocks in the cross tab cells, you will need to unlock the report first to do this
Set the block size to be the same on both cross tabs and then select content is clipped (Size and overflow property of the block)
This will work for both html and pdf output

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by doing the following:

1. Set the Size & Overflow > Width of BOTH crosstabs to the same width in pixels.
2. Unlock the report, select the crosstab Text items in BOTH crosstabs and set them all to the same width (or individual columns to the same width if needed).
3. With the report still unlocked, select the text items in the crosstab 'Rows' and set those to the same width.

It's not pretty, but nothing in Cognos ever is.